# How to use CSS Gradient to create top to bottom fade effect in div box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a top to bottom fade effect from white to grey in a div box that has content in it. I am not sure what css will create this effect.

The result I want looks something like this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jetor.jpg

This is just a cropped image of the website but as you can see it goes from a white color at the top to a darker greyish color to the bottom. This is what I want.

Comment: Its just a css gradient as background. And the image you show has a box-shadow

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0):

Try this css:

```
div {
    height: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, grey 100%)
}
```

You can change the 'white' and 'grey' to hex codes or rgba for specific colours and change the height to whatever you need.